# What is the Esperanto word for the English word "opus"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the correct Esperanto word for the English word "opus"?

"opus"
/ˈəʊpəs,ˈɒpəs/
noun
1.
MUSIC - a separate composition or set of compositions.
2.
an artistic work, especially one on a large scale.

Google Translate returns "opuso" as the translation for "opus", but I was not able to confirm on any Esperanto-related website so far. Other online translators returned "opus", "verko", and "laboro", so I am totally confused.

It would be awesome if an experienced Esperanto speaker could help.

Thank you very much.

Comment: A general remark: The languages we speak influence how we perceive the world and vice versa. For instance you may buy **in** a store, but I buy **from** a store. Single word questions are like asking what is "a store" in language X and assuming that everyone buys in a store. Providing context, what you want to express, gives you better translations. Translate ideas, not words.

Answer (score 2):

The word [*verko*](http://vortaro.net/#verko) covers all artistic or scientific works. Usually that word is enough, but if you need to specify that it is a musical composition, you can use (*muzika*) [*komponaĵo*](http://vortaro.net/#kompona%C4%B5o) (← *komponi* : to compose).

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explaination, Juha!